# moderncv error: tweaklist.sty

Tags: installing, moderncv

I can't get moderncv to work. I get the error:

```
! LaTex Error: File 'tweaklist.sty' not found.
```

What I've done so far is manually install `moderncv` in my texmf tree (`/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv`)

`tweaklist.sty` is in this directory, but when I run

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\begin{document}
;lakdjfl
\end{document}
```

it gives the aforementioned error

Comment: Did u update the name database etc.? I'm not sure how to do this for texlive but there should be an option somewhere.You always have to do this after installing a new package.

Comment: Why do you work with such an outdated version of TeX Live? I really recommend an update of your TeX distribution. Perhaps the newest version TeX Live 2013 ;-) http://www.tug.org/texlive/pretest.html

Comment: Try `kpsewhich moderncv.cls` and check whether TeX does indeed use the version you installed. Then try `kpsewhich tweaklist.sty`, and if any don't give the desired result, run `texhash`.

Comment: I would ditch `tweaklist` and use `enumitem` instead

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I installed the 2013 version of tex live. it is now in the same folder as the 2008 version. when I run my code in texshop it still uses the 2008 version. how can I change the path that is being used?

Comment: @jelle: How did you install TeX Live. Normally there is a new folder `/usr/local/texlive/2013/` The path can be configured in the installation options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give all the information needed to fully answer your question, but since you are using a Mac, there are two basics to pay attention to:

1. Install TeXLive using the [MacTeX installer](http://tug.org/mactex/). This will save you no end of headaches in the future, and furthermore, most of us who use Macs will assume you have this setup.
2. Check your TeXShop preferences. Given that you were previously running TL 2008, it's possible that TeXShop has a direct path to the binaries in the preferences.  With a recent version of TeXShop you should just be able to choose the "Set Default Values" in the Engine preference panel to reset all of the relevant paths etc.